# True Type font coloring

Tags: truetype

How to color true type font ? 
if so, is there any program that can be used to do this ?

I used the font creator program for that purpose but it only produce a font file with black and white colors!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot preserve colour in a TTF font since the specification does not allow for it.